# How to create a list which updates automatically with their objects

Tags: c#

I have created a List which have spaces and one more list with boxes.

1. Each box in the list checks whether it fits into any of the spaces.
2. If it fits then box has to be placed into that space.

   2.1. After placing there may exists some remaining space in it.

   2.2. This space has to be divided into three spaces.

   2.3. These three spaces should be added into the list of spaces and the process repeats until no box fits into any of the spaces in the list.

Here,each space can allot 0 to 100 boxes. My question is how to add these remaining spaces again into the list and delete the space which has already used.

```
Boolean Boxfits, Boxplaced;
foreach (Space space in ListofSpaces)
{
    foreach (Box box in ListofBoxes)
    {  
        Boxfits = checkboxfits.Checkboxfits(box,space);
        if (Boxfits == true)
        {
            Boxplaced =  placethebox.Placethebox(box, space);
            if (Boxplaced == true)
            {
                ListofSpaces =  dividespace.Dividespace(box, space);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is there are a lot of unknown objects for us to actually give you comprehensive solution for example what are the types `Space` `Box` and objects `checkboxfits` `placethebox` `dividespace`. I dont think these are classes in .net. If they are then please let us know.

So for a generic solution think in terms of recursive functions. That will make your life simpler.

Here is a good start.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142292/Recursive-methods-in-Csharp

Try this out but not very sure if it will work

```
public void AddBoxToSpaces(List<Space> ListofSpaces)
{
    Boolean Boxfits, Boxplaced;
    foreach (Space space in ListofSpaces)
    {
        foreach (Box box in ListofBoxes)
        {
            Boxfits = checkboxfits.Checkboxfits(box, space);
            if (Boxfits == true)
            {
                Boxplaced = placethebox.Placethebox(box, space);
                if (Boxplaced == true)
                {
                    //ListofSpaces = dividespace.Dividespace(box, space);
                    AddBoxToSpaces(dividespace.Dividespace(box, space));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here divided spaces should replace the space used.